# cronでgolangのサーバを再起動したい

Tags: cron

cronを使ってサーバを定期的に再起動したいです。
現在はサーバを`ps`でプロセスIDを調べてから、killして`sudo ./exefile`としてから`Ctrl+z`, `bg`でバックグラウンド実行させています。

この作業をcronで自動化したいのですが、どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

Comment: `pkill exefile; sudo ./exefile &` でいかがでしょう?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まぁ、golang はほとんど関係がない様ですが、`syscall.Exec()` を使う方法もあろうかと思います。以下は簡単なサンプルコードです(エラー処理は端折っています)。

**reset_process.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "os/signal"
    "path"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func init() {
    comm, _ := exec.LookPath(os.Args[0])
    ch := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(ch, syscall.SIGUSR1)
    go func() {
        <-ch
        fmt.Println("Catch signal.")
        syscall.Exec(comm, os.Args, os.Environ())
    }()

    // Record my PID
    f, _ := os.Create("/var/tmp/" + path.Base(comm) + ".pid")
    fmt.Fprintf(f, "%d", os.Getpid())
    f.Close()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start countdown.")
    for i := 10; i > 0; i-- {
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", i)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

このサンプルコードでは `SIGUSR1` を受け取るとリスタートします。

```shell
$ go build reset_process.go
$ ./reset_process
Start countdown.
10
9
8
7
Catch signal.    # kill -USR1 $(cat /var/tmp/reset_process.pid) を実行
Start countdown.
10
 :
```

そして(root の) crontab には以下の様なシェルスクリプトを登録します。

```shell
#!/bin/sh

pid_file=/path/to/exefile.pid
exec >/dev/null 2>&1 
[ -s "${pid_file}" ] && {
  pid="$(cat ${pid_file})"
  kill -0 "$pid" && { kill -USR1 $pid; exit 0; }
}
/path/to/exefile &
```

`[ -s "${pid_file}" ]` や `kill -0 "$pid"` としているのは、サーバプログラムを起動していない場合や、稼働途中でサーバプロセスが異常終了してしまった場合を想定しています。

Comment: 最後の`/path/to/exefile &`はなぜ必要なのでしょうか、上のgoコードだけで再起動できるのではないのでしょうか。

Comment: cron による再起動のタイミングの前に何らかの原因でサーバープロセスが終了してしまった場合を想定しています。異常終了した場合には再起動の必要はない、という事であれば、`/path/to/exefile &` の代わりにログファイルにメッセージを出力したり、所定のアドレスにメールを送るなどする処理を追加してもよいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとう御座います。この方法でやりたいと思います。